# how we can use where condition in spark for below hive query?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to spark scala framework, below query having sub-query. As per my limited knowledge spark don't support sub-queries, and also group by function supports multiple columns at a time?

```
select id, email from test1 
where country in (select distinct salary from test2)
group by id ,email ;
```

In spark above query convert into like this, but the problem is how we can use where condition from different data frame. Can we use joins here? How can we convert the whole query into spark?

```
  val m = test1.select("id","email")
   val k = test2.select("salary").distinct
   val l =  m.groupby("id","salary")
```

Comment: Some sample data would be helpful. The column names are a bit confusing.

Comment: i changed two column names only now

Comment: changes done,can u please give me sample answer so that i can go forward

Comment: @mck can you guide me ,please it will be helpful

Comment: i just posted the random columns there,not the original columns .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a semi join to represent the subquery:

```
val m = test1.select("id","email","country")
val k = test2.select("salary").distinct

val df = m.join(k, m("country") === k("salary"), "left_semi")
val l = df.select("id","salary").distinct()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer,but where can i use group by here

Comment: you can use group by in the last line, similar to your original code, but because you're not doing any aggregation, `distinct` is more appropriate.

Comment: if you want to use group by, you can do `df.groupby("id","salary").agg(something)`

Comment: if suppose in subquery if "where not  in "is there ,so which join should i use?

Comment: that will be a "left_anti" join @VamshiKrishnaCH